# Can not change dictionary of com.apple.configuration.managed

Tags: swift, configuration, mdm, managed, userdefaults

I am trying to change the value of for a key in the dictionary 'com.apple.configuration.managed' inside UserDefaults with Swift 5

This is my code:

```
if let dict = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed"){
        var newDict = dict
        newDict["gatewayConfig"] = "Test123"
        do{
          let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newDict, requiringSecureCoding: true)
          UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed")
          //UserDefaults.standard.setValue(["gatewayConfig":"Test123"], forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed")
          UserDefaults.standard.set(object: newDict, forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed")
          //UserDefaults.standard.setValue(data, forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed")
          UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
          let dict2 = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed")
print("New value for gatewayConfig: \(dict2)")

        }
catch {
          print("failed to archive dictionary")
        }
```

When I print the value it still shows the old value and not "Test123". I tried alternative solutions which are commented out yet none of them work.
It does not update the value.
What should I do?

Comment: Use `UserDefaults.standard.set(newDict, forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed")` to set the new value

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've tried UserDefaults.standard.set(newDict, forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed"). It doesn't change the value either.